# Application of Stone-Weierstrass Approximation Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: [0, 1]\to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $\int_{0}^{1} x^nf(x)\, dx =0$,  for all $n= 0,1,3,5,7,\ldots$ (odd integers including zero). Then prove that $f$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$.

IISERKOLKATA interview board ask me this question but I failed to do so.  How can I prove this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_0^{1} x^{n} f (\sqrt x)dx=\int_0^{1} y^{2n} f(y)(2y)dy=0$ for every positive integer $n$ so $f(\sqrt x)=0$ for all $x$ which implies $f \equiv 0$.

(For the equality of the integrals I have used the substitution $y=\sqrt x$)

Comment: In your proof technique works even if I give integral becomes zero for all  odd integers ( excluding zero) ,,  is it so?

Comment: @Siraj Yes, you can exclude $n=0$ from the hypothesis.

Comment: ,,  but I didn't understand that If I take f(x)  = (1+(-1) ^n) x then integration becomes zero for all odd integers although f is not identically zero!!!!!!

Comment: @Siraj You cannot make $f$ dependent on $n$. It has to be fixed function.

Comment: Why so,,  here given that $f$ is just continuous function nothing more,, then why I cannot take f to be dependent on n?

Comment: @Siraj Because then $f$ wouldn't be "a continuous function such that [...] for all odd $n$". It would be a family of continuous functions.

Comment: Ok,,  I understand, thank you

Comment: @Kavi Rama,  Is the result true for arbitrary interval [a, b] instead of [0, 1]

Comment: No. It is not true for $[-1,1]$. If $f$ is an odd function on this interval with $\int_0$=^{1}f(x)dx=0$ then the hypothesis is satisfied. there are lots of non-zero functions satisfying these properties.